# Python asyncio: starting a loop without created task

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-3.7

Could somebody explain me why I can't execute my tasks if I start the loop without any added tasks before? (Python 3.7)

```
import asyncio
import threading    

def run_forever(loop):
    loop.run_forever()

async def f(x):
    print("%s executed" % x)

# init is called first
def init():
    print("init started")

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    # loop.create_task(f("a1")) # <--- first commented task

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_forever, args=(loop,))
    thread.start()

    loop.create_task(f("a2")) # <--- this is not being executed

    print("init finished")
```

If I leave comment on `# loop.create_task(f("a1"))` the execution is:

```
init started
init finished
```

Uncommented execution is:

```
init started
init finished
a1 executed
a2 executed
```

Why so? I wanted to create a loop and to add tasks in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless explicitly stated otherwise, asyncio API [is not thread-safe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading). This means that calling `loop.create_task()` from a thread other than the one that runs the event loop will not properly synchronize with the loop.

To submit the task to the event loop from a foreign thread, you need to invoke [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) instead:

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(f("a2"), loop)
```

This will wake up the loop to alert it that a new task has arrived, and it also returns a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) which you can use to obtain the result of the coroutine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it.